# Disqus notification settings

Tags: disqus

If I check "Which sites do you want notifications for? Check to enable." in http://disqus.com/account/notifications/. Will all moderators receive email notification or just admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disqus notification settings are managed at the account level, so if you turn on notifications from that page it'll only apply to your account.

There's no way to opt another user in/out of emails. The one slight exception is the "Email moderators when a post is flagged" option in the site settings, but that's overridden by your personal account settings.